# Order by with name starts with condition

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using spring boot specification and trying to order a set of results by name such that names that start with "ca" come first. The query looks like -

```
order by name like 'ca%' desc
```

I have used the code

```
cq.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.like(root.get("name"), value + "%")));
```

However, I land me into an error

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST
> node: like near

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. All I had to do was to add these 2 lines of code

```
Expression<Object> queryCase = cb.selectCase().when(cb.like(root.get(NAME), value + "%"), 0).otherwise(1);
cq.orderBy(cb.asc(queryCase));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix your Criteria code, but if you are open to using a named query via the `@Query` annotation in your JPA repository interface, then you may try ordering with a `case` expression:

```sql
order by case when name like 'ca%' then 0 else 1 end
```

Full code:

```java
@Query("select ... from Entity e order by case when e.name like 'ca%' then 0 else 1 end")
public List<Entity> getEntities();
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim ....I am stuck with the criteria code here since its a legacy codebase